# Union of nested monotone classes...

Tags: real-analysis

Is the countable union of nested increasing monotone classes a monotone class?

I know that for algebras this is true, and for sigma algebras it's not. Intuitively since monotone classes can be generated by open sets I'd say the answer is no but I can't think of a good counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem#Definition_of_a_monotone_class) of *monotone class*, the answer is *not necessarily*. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $E_n=\{2k\in\Bbb N:k\le n\}$, and let

$$\mathscr{M}_n=\{\varnothing,\Bbb N\}\cup\{E_k:k\le n\}\;;$$

each $\mathscr{M}_n$ is a monotone class on $\Bbb N$, and $\mathscr{M}_n\subseteq\mathscr{M}_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Let

$$\mathscr{M}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\mathscr{M}_n=\{\varnothing,\Bbb N\}\cup\{E_k:k\in\Bbb N\}\;;$$

then $\mathscr{M}$ is not a monotone class, since $\langle E_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is an increasing sequence of members of $\mathscr{M}$, but $\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}E_k$ is the set of even natural numbers, which is not a member of $\mathscr{M}$.

Comment: M. Scottif you have a moment, would you mind further explaining why the even naturals are not in the union? What throws me off is that the union ranges over all natural numbers, so it seems that any given set of even numbers could be located. I'm sure it's my misunderstanding, but I would love to get beyond it.

Comment: I meant to write @Brian M. Scott